# Initialize Facebook Core SDK for iOS using Objective C?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, facebook, fbsdk

I want to add the Facebook Events tracking to my app, but as it appears Facebook SDK [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#get-started---ios) only provides the code in Swift language:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {    
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {          
    ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
        application,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
    )

    return true
}
```

As I read I should use **FBSDKApplicationDelegate** but I'm not sure how.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Initialize FBSDK**

```
[FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

Comment: This doesn't look like correct obj-C code. Pls confirm if this works for you?

Comment: @Hyder Yes it worked as expected, and yes for sure it's an Objective-C code man

Comment: What @imports are required for this? Didn't work for me either using `FacebookCore`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#import <AuthenticationServices/AuthenticationServices.h>
#import <SafariServices/SafariServices.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-Swift.h>
```

to your import statements and

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                       didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Thanks to the react-native-fbsdk-next package for providing this information (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbsdk-next#32-ios)